# why jackson json deserialization fails to rebuild complex object to original spec

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a complex object that is an ArrayList holding a HashMap with a string and a BigDecimal key/value pair.

I can serialize fine for the object of type

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,BigDecimal>>
```

However, when I try to deserialize it I get an object that looks like:

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Double>>
```

How can I find and build out the right structure in a generic way for reusability. That is, on day 2 I may need to serialize and deserialize ArrayList<Vector<Long, Double>> and I want a generic utility to figure out what the type is and how to deserialize it.

```
[ {
  "testit.0" : 23423423423423423423423423423423.3423423423423423,
  "testit.1" : 278734384738453485837475384573485345.2342342342342342342342365
}, {
  "testit.0" : 23423423423423423423423423423423.3423423423423423,
  "testit.1" : 278734384738453485837475384573485345.2342342342342342342342365
} ]
```

I tried loooking at jackson TypeFactory to create JavaType and using the `getGenericSuperclass()` method on class instance of the top level ArrayList. I could not find a way to look at the member class without getting the child member out first and inspecting that instance with reflection...like: `list.get(0).getClass().getTypeName()`